# JavaScript Module Pattern Vs. JQuery plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery

why would I want to use the Module/Namespacing patterns such as the "revealing module pattern" when writing my applications, as opposed to just writing or getting a bunch of JQuery plugins and applying those?

I guess I could mix them as well. Is there any obvious benefits though, one way or the other?

Thank you.

[EDIT]
I'm really not sure why my question is being downvoted - I don't need help with a piece of code, rather just need clarification on choices.

My confusion stemmed from looking at CSS frameworks such as Foundation. They have a Foundation.js file where they use jquery outside of the plugin architecture. For example, they'll have Foundation.alerts.js, Foundation.forms.js, etc...These are NOT Jquery plugins, yet it seems like that's the preferred way to do it.

Comment: In JavaScript, multiple patterns are often called "module" patterns, could you please provide some simple code examples to compare?

Comment: You don't just use x pattern or y pattern because you can or because everyone else does, you use them to make your code cleaner and/or easier to maintain. If it makes more sense to include an existing plugin or to create your own plugin rather than using x pattern, then do it. Keep in mind plugins can and do use said patterns too.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but I really don't see why my question is being down voted. @KevinB your comments are very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing apples and oranges.  The revealing module patterns is just a means of not polluting the global namespace.  You could very well create your jQuery plugins using the module pattern but you should probably just use a basic closure.  Most every example online of creating a jQuery plugin does that.